# Change the text of an element without wiping out the other contents

Tags: javascript, text, element, preserve

I have a button:

```
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-round like" id="num-likes-entity-{{ key['post'].id }}" >
    <i class="far fa-heart"></i>{{ key['totalLikes'] }}
</button>
```

When someone clicks on this like button, I want to increment the number of likes ({{ key['totalLikes'] }}) without wiping out the `<i>` tag.

Using `.text()` wipes out the `<i>` tag. How can I replace the text without wiping out the `<i>` tag?

Comment: Why don't you wrap the text in a span tag and add an id so you interact with it easier.

Comment: Ok I'll do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Dylan Steele said in the above comments, "wrap the text in a span tag and add an id so you interact with it easier".